# Why do none of the pages in my Wordpress site work?

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am trying to move a Wordpress site to a new server. The domain name is also changing from "olddomain.com" to "newdomain.com."

To this end, I moved all the files over to the new server and set up a virtual host in Apache. I then used a script (http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace instances of "olddomain.com" with "newdomain.com."

The home page of my site is working when I visit it in a browser. However, none of my other pages such as "newdomain.com/about/" are working - they return 404s.

I checked my Apache error log and got the following log.

```
[client 69.184.72.91] File does not exist: /home/david/wordpressSiteFiles/about, referer: http://newdomain.com/
```

Why is Apache looking for a file called "about" on my server? Here is the .htaccess file I have now.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have allowoverride set on the server?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

> allowoverride must be set in your httpd.config or your .htaccess will
>   be completely ignored.
>
> Your server may not have the AllowOverride directive enabled. If the
>   AllowOverride directive is set to None in your Apache httpd.config
>   file, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the
>   server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the
>   filesystem.

Source
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-cant-find-my-new-pages

**I had this same problem a few days ago and this fixed it!**

Comment: Ah thanks! I fixed the problem with these steps. 1) run `a2enmod rewrite` to enable the rewrite engine. 2) place `RewriteEngine On` in my apache2.conf file. That link indirectly led me to the answer - it turned out that mod rewrite was not on. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you solve your problem ^_^ I'm happy today. woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have rewrite rules that need to be updated. Look for a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: hmm, thanks! I posted my htaccess file above that I have now. Do you think there is something wrong with it?

Comment: Ok, it definalty sounds like apache isn't reading your .htaccess then.  Do what the other guy said.